# Running .NET Core 5.0 on Debian Nginx

Tags: linux, .net-core, debian

I wanted to move a project I have working on Windows to run on a Unix machine.

The machine running on Debian 9 with Nginx.

This project runs absolutely fine on Windows with IIS.

I've followed all the instructions on [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/install/linux-debian) created a service for this to run on the start of the machine and Nginx configuration to proxy the connection from the port I want to use to port 5000.

When I start the application running Dotnet Myddl.dll it starts and says it is only listening on port 5000.

Then when I try to access it, I can see a warning.

warn: Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpsPolicy.HttpsRedirectionMiddleware[3]
Failed to determine the HTTPS port for redirect.

I know it is related to my app redirecting to HTTPS and not knowing where to redirect it, but how do I resolve this?

My service

```
[Unit]
Description=Myapp API

[Service]
WorkingDirectory=/var/www/myapp/publish
ExecStart=/usr/bin/dotnet /var/www/myapp/publish/myapp.dll
Restart=always
# Restart service after 10 seconds if the dotnet service crashes:
RestartSec=10
KillSignal=SIGINT
SyslogIdentifier=dotnet-example
User=www-data
Environment=ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Production
Environment=DOTNET_PRINT_TELEMETRY_MESSAGE=false

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target





   server {
    listen        6969;
    server_name   mysite.net *.mysite.net;
    location / {
        proxy_pass         http://localhost:5000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header   Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header   Connection keep-alive;
        proxy_set_header   Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
}
```

EDIT:

I've been trying to resolve this and still can't. When I start the app on the unix machine I get the following

```
root@myhost:/var/www/myapp/publish# dotnet Myapp.dll info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0] Now listening on: localhost:5000 info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0] Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down. info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0] Hosting environment: Production info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0] Content root path: /var/www/myapp/publish
```

Obviously it is missing https option, and I can't figure why.

EDIT2:
I've published the app as self contained for Linux-x64, and now I do not get the warning saying that it couldn't determine the https port, on my browser I get redirected to https://mydomain:5001 when I access it on http://mydomain:6969
Still I do not get the app listening on https on Unix, just on Windows.

EDIT3:
Noticed that if I go to one of my endpoints e.g. http://IP:6969/api/users I get a 500 response.

EDIT4:
When I was loading my application locally, I was getting straight through to the swagger page, such as /swagger/index.html, for some reason my API when complied for Linux does not accept this URL and returns me a 404, but if I get to one of my endpoints e.g. /api/users, it does return me the data I was expecting for.

Answer (score 0):

Default https port should be 5001.

You can set https port following offical [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/enforcing-ssl?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio#port-configuration).

Or disable [relatied middlware](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/enforcing-ssl?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio#usehttpsredirection). Use nginx for https termination if needed.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The issue is that if I run it on windows I have port 5001 available, but on Unix I don't.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to Migrate an API, and as on Windows it was returning me to my swagger page located on /swagger/index.html I was expecting the same to happen, which for some reason, doesn't.

So if I access one of my endpoints (e.g. /api/users) it does work fine.